# Angular - Amazing time picker (ATP) TimePicker doesn't switch to minute after selecting hour

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angular

I am using Amazing time picker in my application, i am not able to automatically switch to minute after selecting hour

component.html

```
<input type="time" atp-time-picker  formControlName="time"  class="form-control">
```

Is there any plugin property which will work?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
changeToMinutes: true
```

other
HTML

```
<button (click)="open()">Time</button>
```

TS

```
open() {
        const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open({
            changeToMinutes: true,
        });
        amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe(time => {
            this.selectedTime = time;
        });
    }
```

source https://github.com/owsolutions/amazing-time-picker/issues/127